# How to unacknowledge message when I run a celery task?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Now I have some sync jobs, which are stateful, so if the task failed, I must unacknowledge message then let them go to the front of `RabbitMQ`. But when I try to raise an error, I found celery still acknowledges this message, and the queue has been cleared.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise ValueError
```

And I found celery task has a method called `retry`, but it will add the task to the back of the queue. This is not what I want.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        self.retry(countdown=15)
```

Even I can't do that with a kill signal:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
```

What should I do? Did celery provide some error so I can raise this error to notify celery don't acknowledge my message?

Comment: try using `retry` in conjunction with `acks_late`.  There is more detail in the Celery's official FAQ  https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry
For failed tasks, you could try setting setting the task priority (not sure how you'll do that with `retry`... as I have not tried out this feature yet). https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html

Comment: @teng `retry` with `acks_late` was not helpful. It will add the task to the back of the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation celery is capable of [RabbitMQs priority queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html). https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-task-priorities

Therefore you should be able to push the retried tasks to the front of your queue by prioritizing them higher than your regular tasks.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        self.retry(countdown=15, priority=9)
```

or

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1892), you can also assign the retried task to a new dedicated queue and assign your ressources to prioritise this queue.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        self.retry(countdown=15, queue='prioritized_queue_name')
```

Comment: I guess it is the nearest way to solve my problem, I didn't find any other solution.

Comment: But, to be honest, if I put a message to another queue, it was still break the queue's order --- the messages after this message will be consumed first. The first solution may need specify `--prefetch-multiplier=1` to promise the highest priority message will be consumed first. It was slower. So I think I'd better implement my own task scheduling system by amql.

Answer (score 1):

On the documentation https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html I found that :

`task_acks_on_failure_or_timeout` is by default `enabled` .

---

So I think you should try a combination of

`task_acks_late=True` + `task_acks_on_failure_or_timeout=False`
to achieve `NO acknowledgement when a task fails`.

Comment: I have tried this option but looks like not work fine. If my task failed, it will not acknowledge my message, but didn't let the message back. So I can't try to fix this task by any other way except kill this worker.

Comment: And, I tried it again, another big problem, if I prefetch 10 messages, and the first one failed, it will not stop here, it will continue to run next tasks, until these 10 messages done, then wait here. That means, the second message, third message... will be consumed before the first one.

Comment: if are looking to process tasks in sequential order in which they are submitted, then i am afraid celery is not designed for those use cases. But if can chain all these tasks together upfront you check about chaining celery tasks